# Uploaded an image to Imgur but people can't leave comments, only share

Tags: imgur

When I upload a few images to Imgur none of them have the space at the bottom for people to add a caption. There are all the share links, but no text field.

What do I need to do in order to allow other users the leave their comments on my uploaded images?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get into the gallery to get captions. How do you do that?

> To get your image into the Gallery, it must be spread all over the Internet and gain a certain level of popularity. This means that you’re still able to upload images and have them remain private (just don’t share them all over the Internet!) while still being able to view the best images out there.

Source: [http://imgur.com/faq#gallery](https://imgur.com/faq#gallery)

Comment: Ah. Thank you, that at least explains it.

Comment: So my next question would be that I posted my image to a subreddit and it doesn't even appear under the "new" tab. Why does that happen? Otherwise how can people find the image to make it popular to make it get in the gallery so people can comment on it??

Comment: To add a new question please use the ask question link. I rather not use the comments section for answering new questions @andyg1

Comment: [link](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23479/16989) @phwd