# Why don't my submissions show up on the New page?

Tags: reddit

When I post an image to a subreddit it doesn't even appear under the "new" tab.

What could be going on for it to not show there?

Comment: Not directly linked to your other post, since it would be any other link or image used going through this

Comment: Sometimes you just have to wait for a while. Reddit just decides to mess up and works after 30 minutes or so.

Answer (score 12):

Reddit FAQ is [suggests](http://www.reddit.com/help/faq#WhydontmysubmissionsshowupontheNewpage) this answer for new submission:

> Why don't my submissions show up on the New page?
>
> I don't know. They really should. Maybe your account has been blocked
>   for some reason.

In my experience I never had this problem. Did you check that your submission is available in your profile under **submitted** tab?

[image]

If it is available there, it should have been available also in **new** page.

Also mentioned [in the FAQ](http://metareddit.com/r/FFFFUUUUUUU)

> Give it a second. It was probably caught by the evil robotic spam
>   filter, but we've created an even more powerful robot to save
>   everything from the filter; it just can take a couple minutes. If it
>   still doesn't work, message the moderators with a link to the comment
>   thread of the post to have it approved

Comment: I gave this a try with some links and they do indeed work, when I check the submitted tab and the new tab. Previously though, when I tried this I (like the OP) was never able to find it in the /new list. I may have to do more tests but I can assure if you search similar posts on the web, users have encountered this issue

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of caching that applies a delay between the submission of a post and the appearance on New tab.

Comment: I believe so, I'm browsing previous entries that I have submitted and they do appear to be in the /new list now when iterating back in time

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with my comments, they show as submitted and the page even says "1 comments" (where I am the only commenter) but the comment isn't shown, even in a clean browser where I'm logged out.  My karma should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it takes a while until it appears. Here is an example where a link posted 1 hour ago appears after a post from 6 minutes ago:

[image: Reddit screenshot]